Getting nginx to pass all routes to Angular index.html
I have an Angular app hosted on nginx that talks to a back-end API. The back-end is working, the app is working when I go to example.com/ but if I go to example.com/custom/path/123 it doesn't get routed to index.html, which is the Angular page. Instead I just get an nginx 404 page.
All I really want is any incoming route (except for the /api and /assets paths) to be passed through to that index.
In my configuration I have this :
server {
  root /var/www/example.com/site-root;

  server-name example.com;

  location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
     # I also tried:
     # try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ index.html;

  } 

  location /assets {
     try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3322/$1;
      # a bunch of working api reverse proxy that doesn't seem to be 
  }
}

The try_files approach is the pattern I have seen in many examples, it appears to be working for everyone else
Am I using it wrong or is this the wrong approach in this scenario?

we need logs, and / does not get proxies, and we need more exact what does not work and where is it located on the filesystem

It should be try_files … /index.html;

Your use of the terms "passed through" is  innappropriate here. In '/' the request is resolved not relayed.

The last part of try_files is a URI for internal redirect and it should starts with /. So the correct use is try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;.
But in this case you probably need to redirect everything to /index.html without trying to find other files. So you could just use rewrite.
You don't need try_files $uri =404 either. That what nginx will do by default.
And you should avoid regexp in location if it could be done without one.
So I think this is what you get:
server {
  server-name example.com;

  root /var/www/example.com/site-root;

  location / {
     rewrite ^ /index.html break;
  } 

  location /assets/ {
  }

  location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3322/;
  }
}

